# How can I get error message from else block in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
begin
    p ''
rescue OneType => e
    #here we can get
    p e.message
else
    #how to get an error message here
```

How can I get an error message from else block in Ruby?

Comment: Can you show an example that raises an exception inside `begin` and then executes the `else` section?

Comment: you may also add multiple rescue for different types of errors: https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/06/ruby-rescue-exceptions/

Answer (score 4):

You cannot because there is no error message. In a begin/rescue/else block the else branch runs when there was *no* exception.

```
begin
  # code that might raise an exception
rescue
  # runs when there was an exception
else
  # runs only when there was no exception
ensure
  # runs in both case
end
```